# Distributing a third-party developed application via App Store

Tags: iphone, app-store, distribution

I am newbie in iOS development and distribution, so may be my question is too basic.

Consider the following, I suppose, very common situation.

Our **company (A)** asked a software **company (B)** to develop an iPhone application for us. Naturally we want to distribute this application via App Store under **our company brand (A)**.

However they say a strange thing like the application can be distributed only under the **developer name (company B)**, and that is unacceptable for us.

What is a possible solution here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that your software developer is confused.

You just need to pay Apple the $99 and register your company with the [iOS Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/).  From there you have a few options:

1. You can give your username and password to your iOS developer.  Then they can create a Distribution Provisioning Profile through your account, reconfigure the project to use that profile, and submit the app to Apple on your behalf.
2. If you've registered with Apple as a company, not an individual, you can invite your developer to join your team via the People tab under Member Center.  That way they can help you administer your app through their own account.
3. Your developer can hand over all the source code to you, and you can handle all the building and app submission yourself.  Be aware that process can be a bit confusing if you're new to the platform.

Comment: I have a small question. Can the last stage of the option 1 (submit the app to Apple) be conducted on our side? Do we need a Mac computer for this?

Comment: You can manage your app's description, pricing, screen shots, etc. via iTunes Connect without a Mac, but you'll need a Mac if you want to build & submit the app binary yourself.  If your developer has created the distribution certificate for you, he'll need to export its private key to a .p12 file so that you can import it.  You'll then install the distribution certificate and provisioning profile.  With these installed, you can build the app using "Build & Archive" in Xcode.  Then you can validate and submit the build through Xcode's Organizer window.

Answer (score 1):

I have uploaded an app on App Store so I know this.

Company A does not need to use Company B's name to put an app on the App Store.

I think the Company B said that because they already have an ID saved to their company's name.

But if you give them $99 then they'll be able to make a new ID saved to company A's name.

Answer (score 0):

If the company(**B**) is willing to give you the product, you can submit to the store by using your [iTunes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITunes) developer account (**A**) and using your own distribution profile, etc.

You can even re code sign the given by **B** by following this way:

> If anyone has the SDK installed on their Mac, plus a developer enrollment, they can re-sign anyone's developer or Ad Hoc apps using the codesign utility from the Terminal command line. (Thus, a developer should be careful about to whom they distribute their Ad Hoc apps for beta testing.)".

Though I didn't check it; I heard about it.

You can try, I believe.